# Leafpad not available for newer releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, text-editor

I see that my favourite text editor Leafpad has been dropped by Debian and now also from Ubuntu versions 19.04 Disco Dingo and onward. How can I get this simple text editor installed now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good news is that it is relatively easy to compile and install Leafpad on a modern Ubuntu system. I demonstrate the 2 step technique on that has worked well most recently on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa:

**Step 1: Dependencies...**

A small number of build tools and dependencies are required, simply copy and paste the following single command into a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall intltool libgtk2.0-dev
```

The package manager will tend to drag in a few more interrelated dependencies along with this list...

**Step 2: Download, compile and build...**

The following single command will download the source, compile and install it. Simply copy the whole code block and paste it into a Terminal window:

```
mkdir -v $HOME/leafpad_build && cd $HOME/leafpad_build && \
wget http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/leafpad/leafpad-0.8.18.1.tar.gz && \
tar xvf leafpad-0.8.18.1.tar.gz && cd leafpad-0.8.18.1 && \
./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/leafpad_build" \
     --pkgname leafpad --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes \
     --default --pkgversion "0.8.18.1" && \
make distclean && sudo ldconfig
```

If you like afterwards you can delete the build directory `$HOME/leafpad_build` or you can keep it as is to recompile at a later stage.

**Obligatory screenshot...**

Below is a screenshot demonstrating a successful build of Leafpad on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa:

[image]

And I hope this has made at least a few Leafpad users a little happier :)

**References:**

- [RM: leafpad -- RoQA; abandoned upstream, rc-buggy](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913765) The Debian bug report that lead to Leafpad being removed...

Answer (score 4):

I found the Leafpad deb installer available for download from these websites:

- https://packages.debian.org/stretch/leafpad
- https://pkgs.org/download/leafpad

I also found Leafpad snap at https://snapcraft.io/leafpad

Maybe (IMHO) the snap version is where the developer and maintainer heads to simplify maintenance and cross platform compatibility.

2020-10-27 Update:
Leafpad installed from Snap store keeps giving error "permission denied" when opening any text file since they moved Leafpad to Snap.
Why?
Why did they ruin this wonderful app???
I give 1 star to Snap not to Leafpad.

2020-10-29 Update:
I found that "Featherpad" is available in the Ubuntu repository and that works perfectly.
Featherpad has a simplistic interface like Leafpad with few options added for code highlighting.
Furthermore Featherpad can properly display the white spaces at the end of line like Windows Notepad.
Leafpad cannot do such a thing :'(
Still i would really like that the Leafpad's author would make Leafpad available again in Ubuntu repository.

2023-03-24 Update:
Leafpad snap still unable to open any text file not created by itself.
I found that the latest Mousepad provides a simple experience a la Windows Notepad and also has some Notepad++.
Mousepad also replaces Gedit very well, so i removed and purged Gedit from my Ubuntu 22.04 system.
If you still encounter issues with Leafpad, I'd recommend to switch to Mousepad.

Comment: The snap version doesn't pick up my GTK theme, and I read that you cannot easily install it. So, that version is out of the question.

I downloaded Leafpad from this link:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/leafpad

The good thing is that it works in 20.04. The bad thing is that it is slow to open on my PC. Mousepad opens just in seconds while Leafpad takes 25 seconds!

It helped me to install the 32-bit version from the Debian packages:
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/leafpad

Comment: I tried Mousepad and then Featherpad and in my opinion i find that Featherpad is better than Mousepad. As i said in my previous log, Featherpad is the only simple text editor that correctly displays end of lines and white spaces like Windows Notepad does. Also Mousepad installs few additional libraries that are Xfce specific and not part of either Gnome or KDE, so if you remove it you end up having some broken libraries hanging around. Featherpad (like Leafpad) is only 1 package.

Comment: Featherpad supports only Black, White, and Gray colors for the text background. For me, it is unacceptable that it doesn't follow the desktop theme and I cannot change it.

Comment: The leafpad snap package in 20.04 does not give a permission denied error when opening text files.

Comment: Featherpad is a perfect replacement for Leafpad.  It pretty much appears that development of Leafpad died with LXDE.  Featherpad is awesome!  =)

Answer (score 1):

### 19.04 and later

The leafpad snap package can be installed in all currrently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo snap install leafpad
```

#### 18.04 and earlier

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install leafpad
```

Answer (score 0):

Try l3afpad on Ubuntu 22.  My quick research reveals it is a fork of leafpad, updated from GTK2 to GTK3.  Visit https://github.com/stevenhoneyman/l3afpad

l3afpad is in the Ubuntu 22 repository and can be installed with

```
sudo apt install l3afpad
```

The snap install of leafpad has some issues with opening files on USB drives (snap appears to have permission issues).  Mousepad worked, but has some very slight differences when jumping between window that I found irritating.  I have not run l3afpad long enough to comment on it (found it today and very happy).