# Leafpad from Snap not works and Gedit is too slow!

Tags: software-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and get many problems.

#1: I couldn't install Leafpad from apt-get. (apt-get install leafpad)
I have install Leafpad from Snap and get many problems!

Problems:
a) Leafpad can't see my printer. I have resolved this issue with:
"sudo snap connect inkscape:cups-control :cups-control"

b) Leafpad screen freezes when I scroll. I can go to the bottom os the document. But the screen is not refresh in real time. When I click in a specific line to type, this line loads a different content.

c) I can't edit documents outside my folder. I use to edit PHP and HTML files in: /var/www/html
By now, I can't edit this files.
I can't open the document using PcManFm (right button and click: Edit using Leafpad). But using Gedit it works!
If I try using terminal:

```
carlos@carlos-desk:/var/www/html$ leafpad gmaps.js 
Gtk-Message: 18:48:52.837: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 18:48:52.837: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
carlos@carlos-desk:/var/www/html$
```

Comment: `leafpad` was replaced with `featherpad`

Comment: You're trying to use depreciated tools; `pcmanfm` & `leafpad` used GTK2 which is EOL because `gimp` completed it's port to GTK3 (development is now GTK4, GTK3 is in maintenance support, GTK2 is EOL). `pcmanfm` (GTK2 in Ubuntu repositories) was mostly ported to GTK3 but then re-ported to Qt5 and is now `pcmanfm-qt` so why use tools that were last supported on *bionic* or 18.04?  Snaps run in containerized environments with limited access to files outside of $HOME, /media, /mnt etc so your use of depreciated tools as you describe to me doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have tested an older answer of mine on 20.04 and it seems to work well enough: https://askubuntu.com/a/1142519/57576 Compiing is involved but I have made it easy :)

Comment: That's a feasible approach I think  .. I like `gpicview` & a few older utilities (inc. `leafpad`) so have them installed on my *hirsute* system.  I've often thought about putting copies in a PPA of those *older* utilities I still use for later releases, just never get around to it.  Be aware there are a number of bugs in `leafpad` that haven't been fixed... the best solution is to use other software in my opinion.

Comment: @guiverc Although I keep a copy of leafpad on my system I agree that leafpad's day is probably well over :(