# How do I satisfy the missing `gtk+-2.0` package when installing Leafpad on Debian-based?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, kubuntu, compiling

When I am preparing to compile [Leafpad](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/) with the `configure` script mentioned in the README, I get this error.

```
checking for GTK... configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0) were not met:
```

`gtk+-2.0` does not seem to be an available package nor can I find a similar-enough one.

System Info

```
Operating System:        Kubuntu 21.10
KDE Plasma Version:      5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version:  5.86.0
Qt Version:              5.15.2
Kernel Version:          5.13.0-51-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform:       X11
```

Comment: Perhaps this might have been useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/1142518/57576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libgtk2.0-dev` package resolved this issue. So, use

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev
```

to install the necessary dependencies. The `configure` script was successful for me after doing this.